# Application-wide variables and helpers

Tags: iphone

I'm sure this question is fairly simple to answer... is there any way to make variables and helpers available application-wide on the iPhone, without using the Application delegate?

Thanks!

------------ edit ------------

Thanks for your help. your comments helped! This is how I implemented my solution...

UIColor+Helpers.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIColor (Helpers) 
+ (UIColor *)getHexColorWithRGB:(NSString *)rgb alpha:(float)theAlpha;
@end
```

UIColor+Helpers.m

```
#import "UIColor+Helpers.h"
@implementation UIColor (Helpers)

+ (UIColor *)getHexColorWithRGB:(NSString *)rgb alpha:(float)theAlpha {
    unsigned int red, green, blue;

    NSRange range;
    range.length = 2;

    range.location = 0; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[rgb substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&red];
    range.location = 2; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[rgb substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&green];
    range.location = 4; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[rgb substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&blue];    

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)(red/255.0f) green:(float)(green/255.0f) blue:(float)(blue/255.0f) alpha:theAlpha];
}

@end
```

One further question... would this be an accepted place to put my configuration global constants?

Comment: Particularly, for example, I was looking for a place to put a helper that would let me get a UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha: from a hex color (#aabbcc), and then use it anywhere in my application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways (well, two at least...)

- You can use plain-old C `extern`s for global variables
- You can write a class method that returns a shared "global" instance (for example, the way `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` works)

The standard warnings about over-use of globals apply...

Edit:

If your desired use case is to add a convenience method to supply hex values to `UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`, a good way to do this is with an Objective-C category. For example:

UIColorHelper.h contains:

```
@interface UIColor (MyUIColorExtensions)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexRGB:(NSString *)rgb;
@end
```

and UIColorHelper.m contains the corresponding `@implementation`.

Once you've created the category on UIColor, the rest of your application can invoke it with something like:

`[UIColor colorWithHexRGB:@"#3366ff"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can create .h file like myConfig.h with defines, global const variables etc and include it in prefetch file [YourProject.pch]. Also you can include there your helper categories.

Answer (score 0):

You could use singleton class, so you have a single instance to contain global vats and helper functions.  I'm about to detail that approach on my blog,http://blog.replicated.co.uk